# Visual Studio 2010 ssrs does not deploy and no errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

- report deployed before ok, now not working (usual story:)
- weird in that /server/Reports/  showed the new deployment timestamp whereas /server/ReportServer/ still shows previous timestamp
- both /server/Reports/ and /server/ReportServer/  paths run the old report
- no clues within the report server log below during deployment

  library!ReportServer_0-1!1cec!03/11/2015-08:37:46:: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
  library!ReportServer_0-1!1ec!03/11/2015-08:37:46:: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/test/Equipment Management/Equipment Maintenance 
  Backlog).
  library!ReportServer_0-1!1cec!03/11/2015-08:37:46:: Call to 
  GetItemTypeAction(/Data Sources/Viewpoint).
  library!ReportServer_0-1!1cec!03/11/2015-08:37:46:: Call to 
  GetItemTypeAction(/Datasets/CompanyLookup).
  library!ReportServer_0-1!1ec!03/11/2015-08:37:46:: Call to 
  GetItemTypeAction(/test/Equipment Management/Equipment Maintenance 
  Backlog/Equipment Maintenance Backlog).
  library!ReportServer_0-1!1ec!03/11/2015-08:37:46:: Call to 
  GetItemDataSourcesAction(/test/Equipment Management/Equipment 
  Maintenance Backlog/Equipment Maintenance Backlog).
  library!ReportServer_0-1!1cec!03/11/2015-08:37:46:: Call to 
  GetItemTypeAction(/test/Equipment Management/Equipment Maintenance 
  Backlog/Equipment Maintenance Backlog).
  library!ReportServer_0-1!1cec!03/11/2015-08:37:46:: Call to 
  GetReportItemReferencesAction(/test/Equipment Management/Equipment 
  Maintenance Backlog/Equipment Maintenance Backlog).
  library!ReportServer_0-1!1cec!03/11/2015-08:37:46:: Call to 
  CreateReportAction(Equipment Maintenance Backlog, /test/Equipment 
  Management/Equipment Maintenance Backlog, True).

Resolved by deleting the old deployed report via Reports Manager (/server/Reports/) before deploying again.

Q Is this normal?  Having to delete a deployed instance of a report before deployment seems flaky and a waste of time.

Q could it be that I am using google chrome(+IE Tab) caching?
Q could it be something with my dev directory setup? 
Q could it be that I am using the freebee version of vs2010 ?
    Q could it be that I am fishing for answers when this is the way deployment is done with vs and m$ environ!

Comment: **No**, you shouldn't need to delete; **Possibly**, try using another browser or clearing cache; **Possibly**, you should go to Project -> Reports Properties and screenshot non-confidential info; **Probably not**, it should work fine.  Get 2013 Community if you think it's actually causing issues.  I've never had to delete a report to deploy, and the only issues I've had were when I fudged up the path to the report folder I intended to deploy to.

Comment: Hey thanks Sonny.  Yeah everything is redeploying now.  I was going through a stack of reports, so was pretty annoying.